# Unable to reverse xticks inside matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have designed a subplot using `matplotlib`. I am trying to reverse the `xticks` of the plot. Please see the sample code-

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate the data
n = 6
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
x = np.arange(n)

# generate the ticks and reverse it
xticks = range(n)
xticks.reverse()

# plot the data
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y)
print xticks # prints [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
plt.show()
```

Please see below the generated plot-
[image]

Please pay attention to the `xticks`. Even though, `ax.set_xticks(xticks)` is used but the `xticks` haven't changed. Am I missing some function call to rerender the plot?

Below is the system information-

```
matplotlib.__version__
'2.1.1'

matplotlib.__version__numpy__
'1.7.1'

python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
```

**Please note that I just want to reverse the ticks and do not want to invert axis.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `ax.set_xticks`, you are currently specifying tick positions which is invariant to the order of the list. Either you pass `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` or you pass `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`. The difference will not be noticed in the ticks. What you instead want is to have reversed ticklabels for which you should do `set_xticklabels(xticks[::-1])`. There are two ways to do it:

**Way 1**

Use `plt.xticks` where the first argument specifies the location of the ticks and the second arguments specifies the respective ticklabels. Specifically, `xticks` will provide the tick positions and `xticks[::-1]` will label your plot with reversed ticklabels.

```
xticks = range(n)

# plot the data
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y)

plt.xticks(xticks, xticks[::-1])
```

**Way 2** using `ax` where you need `set_xticklabels` to get what you want

```
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks[::-1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I realized my mistake. I liked the *Way 2*.

Comment: @RaviJoshi: You are welcome. Glad to help. The first approach is however direct

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
# generate the data
n = 6
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=n)
x = np.arange(n)

# generate the ticks and reverse it
xticks = range(n)
# xticks.reverse()

# plot the data
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y)
# print xticks # prints [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks[::-1])          # <- Changed
plt.show()
```

[image: out]

Comment: Thanks!  It works, however, I couldn't understand the following: changed `range(n)` to `range(n + 1)`

Comment: n+1 is not needed here. range(6) generates 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Thats all what the OP needs. `range(7)` will generate 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Here `6` is not needed

Comment: @Bazingaa well if you say so.

Comment: @meW: Not because I say so, but because there are only 6 bars. So you need indices starting from 0 up to 5 which are generated by range(6).

Comment: I agree. It's just that when I experimented, I didn't receive the last tick with n so used n+1. Either way I agree on range(6) too which makes sense

Comment: That's because the random number generator sometimes doesn't return a particular value so the bar is missing in that case

Answer (score 2):

You can also reverse the order of the axis `ax.set_xlim([5.5, -0.5])`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 6
x = np.arange(n)
y = (x+1) **(1/2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, constrained_layout=True)
axs[0].bar(x, y)
axs[0].set_title('Original data')

axs[1].bar(x[::-1], y)
axs[1].set_xlim(5.5, -0.5)
axs[1].set_title('x index reversed\nand axis reversed')

axs[2].bar(x, y)
axs[2].set_xlim(5.5, -0.5)
axs[2].set_title('just axis reversed')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down - its the proper way to reverse the order of the ticks, rather than changing all the labels.